# Taskpane is not loading with page upon clicking on ribbon icon excel add in

Tags: reactjs, excel, office-js, excel-addins

I am using officeJS with react to create excel add-in. I have added ribbon tab with few ribbon buttons on it and on click on ribbon button I want to show specific pages on task pane. I created ribbon by taking reference from [Excel-shared-runtime-scenario](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/main/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario)

PSB are my controls from manifest:

```
<CustomTab id="ShareTime">
<Group id="ServiceGroup">
    <Label resid="ServiceGroup.Label"/>
    <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
    </Icon>
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="BtnLoginService">
        <Label resid="BtnLoginService.Label" />
        <Supertip>
            <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
            <Title resid="BtnLoginService.Label" />
            <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
            <Description resid="BtnLoginService.Tooltip" />
        </Supertip>
        <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
        </Icon>
        <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
            <FunctionName>btnloginservice</FunctionName>
        </Action>
    </Control>
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="BtnLogoutService">
        <Label resid="BtnLogoutService.Label" />
        <Supertip>
            <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
            <Title resid="BtnLogoutService.Label" />
            <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
            <Description resid="BtnLogoutService.Tooltip" />
        </Supertip>
        <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="SignOutButton.Icon"/>
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="SignOutButton.Icon"/>
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="SignOutButton.Icon"/>
        </Icon>
        <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
            <FunctionName>btnlogoutservice</FunctionName>
        </Action>
        <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    </Control>
    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="BtnHomeService">
        <Label resid="BtnHomeService.Label" />
        <Supertip>
            <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
            <Title resid="BtnHomeService.Label" />
            <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
            <Description resid="BtnHomeService.Tooltip" />
        </Supertip>
        <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
        </Icon>
        <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFunction or ShowTaskpane. -->
        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
            <FunctionName>btnhomeservice</FunctionName>
        </Action>
        <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    </Control>                          
</Group>
```

Below is my command.js file contains the function which are available globally:

```
    import {
    SetRuntimeVisibleHelper,
    updateRibbon,
    signInFromRibbonO365,
    signOutO365FromRibbon,
} from 'utils/excelUtils/office-apis-helpers';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';

export function getGlobal() {
    console.log('init globals for command buttons');
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        return window;
    }
    if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
        return global;
    }
    return undefined;
}

const g = getGlobal();

export function btnloginservice(event) {
    const appHistory = createHashHistory();
    SetRuntimeVisibleHelper(true);
    // appHistory.replace('/login');
    // appHistory.push('/login');
    const port = window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : '';
    const root = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${port}`;
    console.log('path=', `${root}/#/login`);
    window.location.href = `${root}/#/login`;
    // signInFromRibbonO365();
    event.completed();
}

export function btnlogoutservice(event) {
    const appHistory = createHashHistory();
    console.log('Open logout dialog');
    // signOutO365FromRibbon();
    appHistory.push('/logout');
    event.completed();
}

export function btnhomeservice(event) {
    const appHistory = createHashHistory();
    SetRuntimeVisibleHelper(true);
    // history.push('/');
    appHistory.replace('/');
    event.completed();
}

export function btnfeedbackservice(event) {
    const appHistory = createHashHistory();
    SetRuntimeVisibleHelper(true);
    window.open(
        'https://facebook.com',
        '_blank',
    );
    appHistory.push('/feedback');
    event.completed();
}

// the add-in command functions need to be available in global scope
g.btnloginservice = btnloginservice;
g.btnlogoutservice = btnlogoutservice;
g.btnhomeservice = btnhomeservice;
g.btnfeedbackservice = btnfeedbackservice;
```

This is working when I am running code locally using localhost on both online as well as desktop excel, enable/disable ribbon actions are also working correctly.

But when I am deploying application on azure cloud same code not working for desktop excel (office online excel working). Upon click of ribbon sign-in menu its not redirecting page into task pane. Its not redirecting to given path.

**Please help to implement redirection from command function which get called on ribbon click. or suggest what would be the correct approach to implement that**

**Wants to redirect page on task pane on ribbon action.**

**Also its taking time upon clicking on ribbon menu first time to load and execute command function for that action, any idea how we can improve the performance of ribbon menu click**

Comment: Does it work if you place a button to the task pane? So, if you run the command from a task pane window, does it work as expected in Azure? Is the domain whitelisted in your manifest file?

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your comment, Yes its working if we place button in task pane, even directly ribbon click working locally with localhost. Yes domain is whitelisted using AppDomains in manifest<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://app.appserviceenvironment.net/</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>. history.push is not working if I ran flow from deployed application from azure even tried with window.location.href still its not redirecting to the page. But same is working on office365 online excel on chrome.

Comment: I don't think currently it is a possible and supported scenario in OfficeJS - navigate to a web page from a UI-less function on the task pane. The best what you can do is to assign a button for opening a task pane where you can re-navigate to the required page.

Comment: But same is working from localhost if I try to ran flow locally. Is it a correct way to use history.push() or window.location.href to redirect page in task pane? any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display any web page to the user as a result of the button click or some action, try using `window.open('https://anysite.dom')`. This should work if the domain is whitelisted in your manifest.

Comment: window.open() will open new tab. I wants to open same application page in task pane. Like just wants to route the page.